# python unittestしたときに別モジュールを読み込まない

Tags: python, python3

Python3.6.3

ディレクトリ構成
sample_project
┣ bin
┃ ┣ __init__.py
┃ ┣ class_BaseModule.py
┃ ┣ class_module.py
┃ ┗ main.py
┣ test
┃ ┣ __init__.py
┃ ┗ test_class_module.py
┗__init__.py

class_BaseModule.py

```
class base:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def get_base(self):
        return 'base'
```

class_module.py

```
import class_BaseModule
class class_sample:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def get_(self):
        cls = class_BaseModule.base()
        return cls.get_base()
```

main.py

```
import class_module
cls = class_module.class_sample()
print(cls.get_())
```

test_class_module.py

```
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from bin.class_module import class_sample

class Test_class_module(unittest.TestCase):
    def Test_get_(self):
        cls = class_sample()
        actual = cls.get_()
        self.assertequal('base',actual)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

上記の条件でテストすると

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class_BaseModule'

とされてテスト時に読み込んでくれません。

bin\test_class_module.py

```
import class_module
class Test_class_module(unittest.TestCase):
....
```

bin直下にテストモジュールを置く上記条件でテストするとテストが通ります。

テスト時にディレクトリが違う事で宣言したモジュールは読み込みますが明示的に宣言していないモジュールを読まない状態になっていると思います。
今回のディレクトリ構成でclass_BaseModuleモジュールを読む場合ばどのようなコードになりますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test_class_module.py`の`sys.path.append('../')`の箇所で、読み込みたいモジュールは`bin`なので、sys.pathに追加する必要があるディレクトリは'../bin'になります。また、`sys.path.append`は、相対パスでの指定はできません。

それで、絶対パスで`'../bin'`ディレクトリを`sys.path`に追加するか

```
sys.path.append('/path_to_sample_project/sample_project/bin')
```

次のようにして、`'../bin'`ディレクトリの絶対パスを計算してから`sys.path`に追加するようにします。

```
import sys, os
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../bin')
sys.path.append(path)
```

英語版には、よく似た質問 [Running unittest with typical test directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918) があるので、参考にしてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。両方検証できました。絶対パス計算する方法が利便性が高いのでそちらでテストしていきたいと思います